# can numpy's digitize function output the mean or median?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data that I need to group into bins.  Instead of representing the bins as 0,1,2,3...etc.  I would like it to output the mean or median of each bin.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Standard recommendation: usually when you're interested in grouping data and acting on those groups, you want something that has a native `groupby` operation like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) and not bare numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  Is there a good tutorial for the groupby split and combine operations in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a loop-less solution (like most numpy questions require), but assuming you don't have too many bins, and the array is not huge, this should be reasonably fast:

```
x = np.array([0.2, 9., 6.4, 3.0, 1.6])
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 10.0])
inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
inds
=> array([1, 3, 3, 3, 2])

for bin_idx in inds:
    bin_arr = x[inds==bin_idx]
    print bin_idx, np.mean(bin_arr), np.median(bin_arr)
=>
1 0.2 0.2
3 6.13333333333 6.4
3 6.13333333333 6.4
3 6.13333333333 6.4
2 1.6 1.6
```

To create the array:

```
bin_means = np.array([ x[inds==bin_idx].mean() for bin_idx in inds ])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, you are right- This is running incredibly slow..  I do have about 50,000 observations in my training data set and I have another 100,000 in a scoring data set...  I also need to use this for about 20 or so variables.  I guess it is getting late and I can just set up a loop and let my computer have it done in the morning for me:)

Answer (score 5):

You could speed up shx2's code by computing the statistics for each `bin_idx` only once.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.tile(np.array([0.2, 9., 6.4, 3.0, 1.6]), 100000)
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 10.0])

def binstats(x, bins):
    inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
    statistics = []
    binnumber = []
    seen = set()
    for bin_idx in inds:
        if bin_idx not in seen:
            bin_arr = x[inds==bin_idx]
            statistics.append([np.mean(bin_arr), np.median(bin_arr)])
            binnumber.append(bin_idx)
            seen.add(bin_idx)
    return statistics, binnumber

statistics, binnumber = binstats(x, bins)
for (mean, median), bin_idx in zip(statistics, binnumber):
    print('{b}: {mean:.2f} {median:.2f}'.format(b=bin_idx, mean=mean, median=median))
```

yields

```
1: 0.20 0.20
3: 6.13 6.40
2: 1.60 1.60
```

---

By the way, if you have scipy, you could also use [scipy.stats.binned_statistic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html), but the performance is not any better:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# This is a hack to return two statistics with one call to binned_statistic. It reduces the precision of the statistics to `float32`.
def onecall():
    statistics, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
        x, values=x, bins=bins,
        statistic=lambda grp: (np.array([grp.mean(), np.median(grp)])
                               .astype('float32').view('float64')))
    return statistics.view('float32').reshape(-1, 2)

def twocalls():
    means, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
        x, values=x, statistic='mean', bins=bins)
    medians, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
        x, values=x, statistic='median', bins=bins)
    return means, medians
```

---

```
In [284]: %timeit binstats(x, bins)
10 loops, best of 3: 85.6 ms per loop

In [285]: %timeit onecall()
10 loops, best of 3: 86.6 ms per loop

In [286]: %timeit twocalls()
10 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

For comparison purposes, here's how you'd write this sort of thing in `pandas`, using `groupby` and `pd.cut` (similar to `np.digitize`):

```
>>> x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 5*10**5)
>>> bins = np.array([0, 1, 2.5, 10])
>>> s = pd.Series(x)
>>> s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins)).agg(["median", "mean"])
             median      mean
(0, 1]     0.500684  0.500641
(1, 2.5]   1.751121  1.751630
(2.5, 10]  6.243822  6.248801

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Performance seems comparable to those of unutbu's numpy solutions (after tweaking them a bit to accept args):

```
>> %timeit binstats(x, bins)
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop
>>> %timeit onecall(x, bins)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit twocalls(x, bins)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
>>> %timeit s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins)).agg(["median", "mean"])
10 loops, best of 3: 72.5 ms per loop
```

and if you're willing to sacrifice a bit of elegance you can shave some more time:

```
>>> %timeit s.groupby(np.digitize(x, bins)).agg(["median", "mean"])
10 loops, best of 3: 65.2 ms per loop
```

but I don't use `pandas` for the performance, I use it because it makes many common data operations much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more simple, and more general version, of unutbu's code would be

```
import numpy as np
x = np.tile(np.array([0.2, 9., 6.4, 3.0, 1.6]), 100000)
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 10.0])

def binstats(x, bins, funcs):
    inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
    inds2 = np.unique(inds)
    statistics = []
    binnumber = []
    for bin_idx in inds2:
        bin_arr = x[inds==bin_idx]
        statistics.append([f(bin_arr) for f in funcs])
    return statistics, inds2

statistics, binnumber = binstats(x, bins, [np.mean, np.median])
print(statistics)
for (mean, median), bin_idx in zip(statistics, binnumber):
    print('{b}: {mean:.2f} {median:.2f}'.format(b=bin_idx, mean=mean, median=median))
```

This might be preferable since it allows you to use an arbitrary number of functions in your statistics. Also creating the set ahead of time might be quicker.